# VueJS: dynamically set component's methods

Tags: javascript, vue.js, single-page-application

I have a SPA application with single page components; I want to import certain methods for the component based on my route's name. How can I achieve that in Vue? Something like:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="foo in customMethod()">{{foo.bar}}</div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    methods: {},

    mounted: function() {
        switch(this.$route.name) {
            case "route.name":
                this.methods = require('./external-script.js');
                break;
            case "another.route.name":
                this.methods = require('./another-external-script.js');
                break;
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: Why do this, since you already have a switch statement so you can just invoke different functions based on the route name? This feels like an XY problem to me.

Comment: I need to invoke the methods from my template as well.

Comment: Methods have the same names and return the same type, but their content is different. Is painful to declare them here and create switch statements inside each to modify their behaviour; I'd prefer to import them directly.

Comment: Then in your template invoke a universal method, and in the method you use switch statements to determine which specific method you want to invoke based on route name. When you import those scripts you can always use custom aliases anyway. I don't see the reason behind your roundabout approach here.

Comment: I could use such workarounds; but I want to know if it is possible to set component's methods dynamically. I mean, literally dynamically.

Comment: I think it would be easier to create an object whose keys will be the route names and the values will be your external scripts. Then you will refer to your methods like `objectContainer[this.$route.name].yourMethodName()`

Comment: You can't assign the methods object from within a component, or it would lack the special configuration Vue performs during component creation.  Use dynamic components or a slot wrapper component.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Will find some other way then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dan mentioned in comments, **this is impossible**. So I've approached Strategy pattern concept as suggested by Evandro. I'm importing the external files based on route name when component is mounted.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="foo in method1()">{{foo.bar}}</div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data: function() {
        m: {},
        // ..
    },

    methods: {
        method1: function(params) {
            return m.method1(params)
        },

        method2: async function(params){
            return await m.method2(params, this.another_param);
        },

        // ...
    },

    mounted: function() {
        switch(this.$route.name) {
            case "route.name":
                this.m = require('./external-script.js');
                break;
            case "another.route.name":
                this.m = require('./another-external-script.js');
                break;
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

Note that depending on how your component is mounted, including scripts based on route within `mounted()` may not always work.

Answer (score 1):

This description seems like a problem which Strategy design pattern can solve, because you need one different behavior according to the route name. Check out this [post](https://dev.to/carlillo/design-patterns---strategy-pattern-in-javascript-2hg3). If it's not your intention, you can try the Vue [dynamic components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html).